# Delete rows in Dataframe based on condition in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am familiar on how to remove rows within a Dataframe based on a condition as:

```
df1 = df1.drop(df1[<some boolean condition>].index)
```

Let df1 and df2 be equally sized DataFrames. The problem is to remove the same index rows in df2 that satisfy the aforementioned condition for df1. I am looking for an elegant solution instead of keeping the indexes and then iterating over them again for df2.

Example:

```
         df1                
    index  value
    1        4
    2        5
    3        6
    4        3
    1        1
    2        5
    1        3
    2        3
    3        2
    4        2
    5        1
    6        7
    7        12

      df2   
 index  value
    1        4
    2        5
    3        7
    4        3
    1        1
    2        109
    1        44
    2        3
    3        2
    4        2
    5        1
    6        7
    7        12
```

The indexing is not consecutive so a simple df.drop won't work. Its based on groups created before.

Comment: Define "same rows". If you mean same index, then just store `df1[<some boolean condition>].index` in a variable (say `idx`) and use `df2 = df2.drop(idx)`.

Comment: yes I mean same indexed rows in equally sized dataframes

Comment: Can you add a quick example of how you want it to work?  Like put two 3x3 data frames and show us how you want it to work?  I think I can solve it but I don't know exactly what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should fix your indexing in your dataframes. What you want to do will not work unless the indexes are consecutive since you will remove multiple rows by deleting by index. You should try and avoid [many to many relationships in data analytics - they simply cause more problems then they solve](https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SDM03CD/page_37.htm)).

Try something like this:

```
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()
for indexes, row in df1.iterrows():
    if df1.columnname = 2: #imaginary value, place Boolean condition here
       df1.drop(df1.index[[indexes]])
       df2.drop(df2.index[[indexes]])
```

Comment: I can always transform the indexes group-wise with df=df.groupby('Person').apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).drop('Person',axis=1).reset_index()  assuming that Person is the groupby variable

Comment: Did the fix above help?